# Getting contract work in the US

Tags: united-states

I'm a UK resident and I would really like to work in the USA, preferably on a 6-12 month contract.

I feel that I have a good skill set (Masters degree, professional accounting qualification and outside work projects) and get a lot of attention from companies and recruiters here in the UK but am worried it's a lot of hassle for a US company to hire someone from the UK for a non permanent role.

I also don't want to take a permanent role as i'm not yet sure I would relocate permanently so don't want to be disingenuous.

Are there any resources that would help me with this particular scenario?

Comment: Just seemed like a good amount of time to see how I like working abroad and if I'd like to stay there long term

Comment: Ok good point. I guess I should look for a year minimum with the possibility of relocation. It's seems that will help my chances.

Comment: From what I've read, the UK has 3 big accounting qualifications, of which I hold a CIMA. The U.S. Has one major qualification called the CPA. I would say they're directly comparable as there is nothing above them. At a glance, the CIMA looks more difficult as its 15 exams vs the CPA (4 IIRC) but I can't say anything for the content so that may not be true.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Are there any resources that would help me with this particular
>   scenario?

You could contact an Agency in the part of the US where you would like to work.

They can advise you of conditions required for a work Visa, and if they have any openings that match your skills and experience.

Six months is a rather short period for many contracts, but perhaps 12 would work. In my experience, companies tend to favor those who might be around longer if needed, and who know where they want to be. They may be concerned that you will decide you don't like the US after a few weeks and will leave.

You could also think about working for a UK-based company that has offices in the US.

Additionally, if you are a new graduate, your university's placement office may be able to help.

Comment: A UK company is only going to send trusted long term employees to the states. You are unlikely to find a company that will hire you and then send you to the states just after joining.

Comment: From what I've read, contractors are not used in the U.S. as commonly as they are in the UK. Is this the case or has it changed?

Comment: Awesome, that's promising for me then